# Convert two structs where the Types of the properties are different but the underlying types of those types are identifcal

Tags: go, struct

I've read around and rightfully so, Golang doesn't allow you to assign the data from one struct to another if the types are different. However, in my case, I have a need to make the packet size of the data as light as possible (very weighty inbound JSON property names, and very large json requests) but when fetching, we only need short codes for the properties.

```golang
// FrequencyCondition ...
type FrequencyCondition struct {
    Occurrence     string   `json:"occurrence,omitempty"`
    IntervalUnit   string   `json:"interval_unit,omitempty"`
    IntervalType   string   `json:"interval_type,omitempty"`
    Comparison     string   `json:"comparison,omitempty"`
    Identifier     string   `json:"identifier,omitempty"`
    ValueText      []string `json:"value_text,omitempty"`
    ValueInt       []int    `json:"value_int,omitempty"`
    ValueTimestamp []string `json:"value_timestamp,omitempty"`
    ValueDate      []string `json:"value_date,omitempty"`
    ValueDecimal   []string `json:"value_decimal,omitempty"`
}

// FrequencyConditionMinified ...
type FrequencyConditionMinified struct {
    Occurrence     string   `json:"o,omitempty"`
    IntervalUnit   string   `json:"iu,omitempty"`
    IntervalType   string   `json:"it,omitempty"`
    Comparison     string   `json:"c,omitempty"`
    Identifier     string   `json:"i,omitempty"`
    ValueText      []string `json:"vt,omitempty"`
    ValueInt       []int    `json:"vi,omitempty"`
    ValueTimestamp []string `json:"vts,omitempty"`
    ValueDate      []string `json:"vdt,omitempty"`
    ValueDecimal   []string `json:"vdc,omitempty"`
}

// Condition ...
type Condition struct {
    ConditionType         string              `json:"condition_type"`
    Conditions            []*Condition        `json:"conditions,omitempty"`
    NextConditionOperator Conditional         `json:"next_condition_operator,omitempty"`
    Input                 *InputCondition     `json:"input,omitempty"`
    Event                 *EventCondition     `json:"event,omitempty"`
    Frequency             *FrequencyCondition `json:"frequency,omitempty"`
}

// MinifiedCondition ...
type MinifiedCondition struct {
    ConditionType         string                     `json:"t"`
    Conditions            []MinifiedCondition        `json:"c,omitempty"`
    NextConditionOperator ConditionalMinified        `json:"nco,omitempty"`
    Input                 InputConditionMinified     `json:"i,omitempty"`
    Event                 EventConditionMinified     `json:"e,omitempty"`
    Frequency             FrequencyConditionMinified `json:"f,omitempty"`
}

type Response struct {
    Conditions []*Condition `json:"conditions"`
}

type ResponseMinified struct {
    Conditions []*ConditionalMinified `json:"c"`
}
```

Whilst this seems silly, when there are thousands of these being returned tens of thousands of times a day, we save quite a lot of bandwidth from the DB server > App.

```golang
func ParseJson(data string) {
    var response Response

    err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(data), &response)

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }

    var minifiedResponse = ResponseMinified(response) <--- Error here
```

Notice the only difference is at the very top level of the structs Response/Condition - under that, it's all OK. But the internal types of those Minified structs end up referencing types that are identical.

Is there any smart, or better way of converting than iterating through each struct and manually assigning the properties, then forming the struct back together again?

Comment: Have you considered unmarshalling to an `interface{}`? See [JSON and Go](https://blog.golang.org/json) "Generic JSON with interface{}".

Comment: @Schwern - not sure how that helps? I tried unmarshalling to map[string]interface{} which is what I use for unstructured (or unknown) json. But it's the same error when I try to cast that value into the ResponseMinified Struct. The important thing is all the JSON property names get collapsed into those single/double char names

Comment: *"Is there any smart, or better way of converting than iterating through each struct and manually assigning the properties, then forming the struct back together again?"* I'm afraid not, you have to do it the hard, verbose way. Note that only the FrequencyCondition & FrequencyConditionMinified have identical underlying types, the rest of the types in the question do not, you can read the [type identity](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_identity) spec section to find out why. For simple illustration purposes, see [here](https://play.golang.org/p/PjuAnLAIe0r).

Comment: @mkopriva I feared as much. In general I love the verbosity of Go, but for things like these, it would be nice to have some function that could recurse the struct Properties and see that when a property has type X, and all the properties of type X are the same as type Y that it would be OK to type cast them.

Comment: @Trent you could use `reflect` to implement such a function, and it may even make sense to do that if you have many such type variations that you need to convert between, however for a small number of types I personally would just do the manual work and be done with it.

Comment: @Trent Unmarshelling to `interface{}` means you don't need two parallel sets of structs. You only need one. You will have to translate the keys, but that's a simple map. For example, the value for both `o` and `occurrence` would go into `FrequencyCondition.Occurrence`.

Comment: @Schwern - I see - will give it a go and let you know how I go. Thanks